# react image gallery custom play function

Tags: reactjs, carousel, gallery, image-gallery

I want create custom play button outside the ImageGallery Carousel and toggle play and pause by accessing play() and pause() methods through refs (NOTE: not renderPlayPauseButton)
[image]

```
  import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
  import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";

  import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
 
  const images = [
    {
       original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/",
       thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/"
    },
    {
      original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/",
      thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/"
    },
    {
      original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/",
      thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/"
    }
  ];

  export default function App() {
    const playRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(playRef);
    }, []);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => playRef?.current?.pauseOrPlay()}>Play</button>
        <ImageGallery
          ref={playRef}
          items={images}
          showThumbnails={false}
          showFullscreenButton={false}
          showPlayButton={false}
          infinite={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Need help !!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Javascript version:

```
export default function App() {
  const playRef = useRef(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const playOrPause = () => {
    setIsPlaying((prev) => {
      if (playRef) {
        playRef.current[prev ? "pause" : "play"]();
      }
      return !prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ImageGallery ref={playRef} items={images} />
      <button onClick={playOrPause}>{isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Typescript version:

```
export default function App() {
  const playRef = useRef<ImageGallery | null>(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const playOrPause = () => {
    setIsPlaying((prev) => {
      playRef?.current?.[prev ? "pause" : "play"]();
      return !prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ImageGallery ref={playRef} items={images} />
      <button onClick={playOrPause}>{isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the example:

Javascript version

[image: Edit festive-voice-0uioso]

Typescript version

[image: Edit snowy-morning-8t1cwb]

Comment: thank you , but i keep getting this error (property) React.MutableRefObject<null>.current: null
Object is possibly 'null'
How to define type for useRef ?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated my answer with the typescript version